# Join 2 tables with same fields without duplicates

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables with the same lines - I need to attach these tables to two lines (product and vint), and the bid's id should not be repeated in bids and this for orders , if it already is then NULL is needed.

```
SELECT b.product, b.vint, o.id as offer_id, b.id as bid_id from bids b LEFT 
JOIN offers o ON b.product = o.product AND o.vint=b.vint group by 
b.product, b.vintage, b.id
 UNION
SELECT o.product, o.vint, o.id as offer_id, b.id as bid_id from bids b RIGHT 
JOIN offers o ON b.product = o.product AND o.vint=b.vint group 
by o.product, o.vint, o.id
```

Example:
        we need:

```
 product    |   vint  |  bid_id | offer_id
 Pro_1      |    s12  |   1     |   3
 Pro_2      |    s13  |   2     |   NULL
 Pro_1      |    s13  |   4     |   1
 Pro_2      |    s11  |   NULL  |   2
 Pro_3      |    s10  |   5     |   4
```

but my result is : with duplicates

```
product     |   vint  |  bid_id | offer_id
Pro_1       |    s12  |   1     |   3
Pro_2       |    s13  |   2     |   1
Pro_1       |    s13  |   4     |   1
Pro_2       |    s11  |   NULL  |   2
Pro_3       |    s10  |   5     |   4
Pro_1       |    s12  |   1     |   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should group by bid_id one more time after union 2 tables like this.

```
select * from (
   SELECT b.product, b.vint, MAX(o.id) as offer_id, MIN(b.id)  as bid_id from 
   bids b LEFT JOIN offers o ON b.product = o.product AND o.vint=b.vint group 
   by b.product, b.vintage, b.id
     union 
   SELECT o.product, o.vint, MIN(o.id) as offer_id, MAX(b.id)  as 
   bid_id from bids b RIGHT JOIN offers o ON b.product = o.product AND 
   o.vint=b.vint group by o.product, o.vint, o.id
) as demo_table group by bid_id
```